# Which carbon electrode gets plated with Zinc on a beaker with zinc sulphate solution?

Tags: electrolysis

In a beaker containing zinc sulpate and two carbon electrodes connected to a battery, which electrode gets electro plated with Zinc? Why?

Comment: This is an interesting question to solve this question one needs an understanding of exchange current densities for zinc cation reduction and proton reduction on the electrode.